# Windows Authentication 401.2 Error using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I'm having a hard time fixing an error that I currently have and I hope you can help me with it.

I am developing a little ERP-WebSite that is going to be used within an intranet. Naturally I want to use Windows authentication to make it as comfortable as possible for the user. I developed the Website using Visual Studio 2008 and its integrated development server. Recently I migrated to VS2013 and .NET 4.5. Code wise everything went good and I am able to build everything but here comes the problem. Because I am using VS2013 now I also have to use IIS Express. When I try to debug the Website i receive a 401.2 Error. Error Code 0x80070005. On VS2008 everything worked perfectly and I am 99% sure I have the IIS config set up currectly. Here are the relevent parts:

applicationhost.config:

[image]

I also set the according values in the Project Settings in VS2013. 
I'm kind of lost right now. Any help will be much appreciated!

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

After playing around with IISExpress for way to long now, I finally got it to work again. Something must have been wrong with my previous eddits of the applicationhost.config file of the IIS Express. I just deletet it and let VS13 recreate it. Afterwards I was able to run my site using IISExpress. I hope this might help someone who has the same problem as I do. Sadly i realized that it is painfully slow. It takes almost 2 minutes for some pictures to get loaded etc.. What could be the cause of that ? I also tried using the full IIS Version (with Win-authentication installed) but when I run my site using the local IIS I receive an XML-parsing error: No element found. Using the local IIS would be a lot faster than using IISExpress, so I'd very much like to fix this Error.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: find here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942043

Comment: Sadly, I already tried these steps. No luck...

Comment: Have you enabled Windows authentication feature on this machine?

Comment: I have. As well as the management console.

Comment: I might add that the steps that Nazir proposed are meant for a "full" IIS and not IIS Express. Same goes for enabling the Windows Authentication feature. I am still looking for a solution to this but I'm starting to think this might be a bug with IISExpress 8.0. I tried creating a new Web Project and activating the Windows authentication on it but its giving me the same error